# docker build in gitlab can't find packages to build

Tags: docker, proxy, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a local gitlab runner that is behind a proxy. When building docker images, it fails to access the repos.

Errors:

> Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
> Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.98.132). - connect (111: Connection refused)

Relevant part of CI/CD

```yaml
build_image:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  variables:
    HTTPS_PROXY: http://proxy.example.com:3128
    HTTP_PROXY: http://proxy.example.com:3128
    NO_PROXY: docker
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login nexus-docker.example.com:5000 -u $NEXUS_USER -p $NEXUS_PASS
  script:
    - docker build -t nexus-docker.example.com:5000/occ/groupsyncer:latest .
  except:
    - master
```

gitlab runner config:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.example.com/"
  token = "REDACTED"
  executor = "docker"
  cache_dir="/cache"
  clone_url = "https://gitlab.example.com/"
  environment = ["https_proxy=http://squidproxy.example.com:3128", "http_proxy=http://squidproxy.example.com:3128", "HTTPS_PROXY=squidproxy.example.com:3128", "HTTP_PROXY=squidproxy.example.com:3128", "no_proxy=gitlab.example.com", "NO_PROXY=gitlab.example.com,docker,thealias"]
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock","/opt/gitlab-runner/cache:/cache:rw"]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:20.10.16"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    shm_size = 0
```

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

```ini
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://squidproxy.example.com:3128" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://squidproxy.example.com:3128" "NO_PROXY=.example.com,.occdev.example.com" "http_proxy=http://squidproxy.example.com:3128" "https_proxy=http://squidproxy.example.com:3128"
```

*Domain edited to example.com for posting*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container build process does not inherit environment variables by default. You must either (1) configure your dockerfile with the proxy variables or (2) pass in these variables as part of the build process with build args.

For example, in your dockerfile, you might add the following `ARG` instructions to your dockerfile:

```
FROM foo:tag
ARG HTTP_PROXY=defaultvalue
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=defaultvalue
RUN apt update && apt install -y ...
# or whatever...
```

You can pass this variable through to the build process when calling `docker build`

```bash
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY="${HTTP_PROXY}" \
             --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY="${HTTPS_PROXY}" \
             -t nexus-docker.example.com:5000/occ/groupsyncer:latest .
```